# R: Parallel Processing Error: "Errorr in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 5 nodes produced errors; first error: Objekt 'RAD' not found"

Tags: r, error-handling, parallel-processing, cpu-cores

I am currently conducting an CRQA on heart rate and respiration data. I try to parallelize the computation in the following way, because I want to run them on an external server:

```
RAD = round(median(Param_list$radius), digits = 2); RAD # defining the final parameter settings
DEL = max(Param_list$delay); DEL 
EMB = max(Param_list$emddim); EMB

my_crqa = function(x, y){
  crqa::crqa(x, y,
             radius = RAD, embed = EMB, delay = DEL,
             rescale = 2, normalize = 2,
             mindiagline = 25, minvertline = 25, tw = 0, whiteline = FALSE,
             side = "both", method = "crqa",
             metric = "euclidean", datatype = "continuous")
}


memory.size(max = TRUE)
core = round(detectCores()*0.8, digits = 0)
cl<-makeCluster(core, type="SOCK")
clusterEvalQ(cl, c("my_crqa", "EMB", "DEL", "RAD"))
CRQA_list = clusterMap(cl, my_crqa, HR_clean, HR_clean)
stopCluster(cl) # Stop cores properly.
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

> "Errorr in checkForRemoteErrors(val) :    5 nodes produced errors;
> first error: Objekt 'RAD' not found"

Why does the cluster not find the RAD, but the the other variables? Also, when I ran the code earlier it worked.

I appreciate any tip!

Best,
Johnson

Comment: Why do you assume it finds the other variables? It stops after the first error and doesn't try to evaluate the other variables. Anyway, use `clusterExport` to export your variables to the nodes.

Comment: Of course, thats true. Thanks that worked :)